# Насколько часто приходиться работать с gradle?

Tags: java, android

Я наткнулся на статью по `gradle` , сижу уже 2 часа читаю и понимаю, что тема `gradle` достаточно объемная.

И вот по этому поводу возник вопрос, я новичок, но уже немного работал с проектами и `gradle` использую только когда нужно подключить библиотеку или еще какую нибудь мелочь поправить типо версии `sdk` или `versionCode` и на этом все.

Вопрос такой, действительно ли при разработке приложений андроид используются еще какие нибудь возможности `gradle`? Потому, что пока я не могу понять зачем такое количество возможностей содержит этот файл и кто их использует?

Comment: да, действительно. В одном из моих проектов `build.gradle`, например, содержит не много - не мало, 270 строк. В нем описано как именно нужно билдить проект в зависимости от выбранной конфигурации. Кроме того, проект сорержит отдельно интефейс и имплементацию в отдельном dex файле

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью `gradle` можно:

- Задать кастомное имя скомпилированного приложения;
- Определить несколько [вариантов сборки](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants) пориложения (фулл, демо)
- Подключать репозитории
- [Подписывать приложения](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#release-mode)

Это часть полезных функций. Инструмент полезный и мощный.